# Best design for referring to compile-time set of values at runtime

Tags: c++

I am designing an internal API that deals with images.
As part of this, I hit this use case where:

- I specify an image format as a single value.
- An image format implies a collection of settings (values to pass to OpenGL, fragment shader code, texel bit size, …).

In essence, a trait would be perfect… except the image format is not known at compile time.

I am looking for a good way to express this in C++ (C++17 allowable).

So far, here is an attempt that *works* but feels very awkward:

```
// pixel_format_def is a structure with static constexpr members

using R8 = detail::pixel_format_def<GL_R8, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE>;
using RG8 = detail::pixel_format_def<GL_RG8, GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE>;
// ... many others
using PixelFormat = std::variant<R8, RG8>;
```

The actual `pixel_format_def` has more fields. It is then used like this:

```
void someFunc(PixelFormat format /*, other args */)
{
    std::visit([&](auto tag) {
        using Format = decltype(tag);
        someFunc(Format::format, Format::type/* other args */);
    }, format);
}
```

Basically this does tag dispatching, with `std::variant` holding a tag.

It fulfills my requirements:

- If the format is known at compile time, the compiler inlines the call and removes the `std::visit`. For instance:

  ```
    someFunc(RG8());
  ```

  will be inlined (at least by clang and gcc) directly to

  ```
    someFunc(GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
  ```
- Yet it works if the format is only known at runtime. In which case std::visit will pick the correct values Without passing around a big structure.

It feels really awkward though, almost a mis-use of `std::variant`. And I am not sure it would pass code review. Any better idiom?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using a `map` or similar object? Is there some memory overhead issue that you have?

Comment: It cannot be created at compile time, which means the compiler cannot optimize the case where the type is known at compile time (plus all the usual caveats of initializing global variables during program startup)

Comment: "*which means the compiler cannot optimize the case where the type is known at compile time*" What does that mean in this context? Because you don't *really* have types; you're abusing the type system as a way of storing collections of values. So what optimization exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: Sorry I meant image format. Whenever the image format is known at compile time, eg if I call `someFunc(RG8())`, the compiler inlines it as `someFunc(GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)`. Neat and efficient, no need to go looking for the values in some runtime structure. — I just added that precision to the question btw.

Comment: Exactly like if it was a trait. Actually a trait would be perfect… except the image format is not *always* known at compile time. Often, but not always.

Comment: Is "looking for the values in some runtime structure" *really* a performance bottleneck in your application, or are we talking about a premature optimization here? And if it is a bottleneck, have you tested it in real-world performance? Because in order for `someFunc` to be "inlined", it'd have to be a template, right? Which means you have to instantiate `someFunc` for *every* image format type. Which means you will have a lot of these lying around, so if you're calling a bunch of different `someFunc<type>` instantiations, you'll miss a lot on the instruction cache.

Comment: No it's not a template. That does not prevent inlining though, the compiler just realizes that given the implementation it's faster to inline the inner call than go the indirect way. And then while inlining the inner call it removes the std::visit since it can deduce all paths are unused but the correct one. ­— The point is not one of optimisation but of design - passing around a data-structure with all the settings gives the API user the chance to get it wrong. Only a few dozen specific combinations make sense.

Comment: "*No it's not a template.*" Then how can one function take both `R8` and `RG8` when they are two unrelated types? It has to either be overloaded or be a template.

Comment: It takes a `std::variant<R8, RG8>` (there are more, but that's the idea). It's described in first code block :)